# Segmentation error when releasing but fine when debugging? Cs50 arrays caesar assignment

Tags: c, cs50

I have a few questions regarding segmentation fault, why is it that when I am debugging my code it is fine but when it is released segmentation error follows? I have read online where it says debugging forces the code to run in the correct order, since I'm following the cs50 course for arrays, my knowledge of coding is just till there. Please do provide some feedback regarding my code, i'm trying to look at ways to improve my very very long and untidy code. Thank you very much.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <ctype.h>
#include <cs50.h>
#include <string.h> 

int main(int argc, string argv[])
{
    if (argc != 2) 
    {
        printf("Usage: ./caesar key\n");
        return -1;
    }
    int n = strlen(argv[1]);
    for (int z = 0; z < n; z++)
    {
        if (isalpha (argv[z]))
        {
            printf("Usage: ./caesar key\n");
        }
    }

    if (argc == 2)
    {    
        {   
            int key = atoi(argv[1]);
            string plaintext = get_string("Plaintext: ");
            int y = strlen(plaintext);
            printf ("Ciphertext: ");
            for (int i = 0; i < y; i++)
            {
                if (key >= 26)
                {
                    printf("%c", (char) plaintext[i] + (key % 26));
                }
                else if (key < 26)
                {
                    printf("%c", (char) plaintext[i] + key);
                }
            }
        }
    }
    return 0; 
}
```

Comment: Did you try using a debugger, such as `gdb`?

Comment: yes, it works fine in cs50 ide debugger

Comment: What does "when it is released" mean? Do you mean a non-debug optimzed build? If so you can still compile with debug symbols and run with a debugger can't you? Or when your allocated string memory is released i.e. explicitly freed (which you're not doing?), or any automatic cleanup when the process ends?

Comment: `isalpha (argv[z])` is wrong. You meant `argv[1][z]`, and probably meant to return after printing the error.

Comment: @Rup why do you think so. He checks if the char is alphanumeric. Not if it's a null byte.

Comment: @Rup He is not checking for that, but it's clear that he wants them to be only numeric.

Comment: @MaxxikCZ The `isalpha (argv[z])` check? argv[z] means a pointer to the zth argument, and is of char* type. isalpha accepts a char or int. You should get compiler warnings for this, and if you're not you should turn them on. If you want the zth character of the first argument that's argv[1][z].

Comment: Numeric - OK, yes, fair point. He meant `!isdigit` then, not `isalpha`, since not all non-digits are alpha.

Comment: Oh, it's clear then. Just do `argv[1][z] < 0x30 || argv[1][z] > 0x39`

Comment: The actual application of the key is wrong too. It'll process non-alpha characters, and won't wrap the sum around from Z to A, e.g. if your key is 13 and you enter 'N' then you should get 'A', but you'll get '['.

Comment: When performing the char value adjustment you do not need a conditional. All you need is printf("%c", (char) plaintext[i] + (key % 26));

Comment: Ah is see where the problem is now, yes, Argv[1][z] is the one that should be used instead. Thank you very much, i now see my mistake. Also, i apologize for not knowing programming jargon. Literally started last week and i saw someone post about the same question and they used the term "Release". What i meant was just using make caesar and running ./caesar key at the command line

Comment: Will take a look at the key again

Comment: Right, sorry, yes. If you build this so you can run it then that's probably just "compiled". In that context, "released" usually means "packaged up and uploaded somewhere for other people to download". However there's also "release" as the opposite of "debug", which you'll see in Visual Studio for example, meaning an optimized build without debug symbols included, and then you might hear "release" in the context of finishing with allocated memory.